# How can we share the Icon image with dynamic content overlap on it through implicit intent?

Tags: android, android-implicit-intent

Here points, streak and level are dynamic I want to share this whole image with the dynamic text of points, streak and level with implicit intent. How can I do this please help me out?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By *implicit intents* to you mean intent to open another app ?
If you want to share the whole image you have to first create a snapshot

Comment: and how can I create a snapshot of that?

Answer (score 0):

I worked on same type of functionality

First you have to make single picture.
For this purpose you can use Sticker View Library https://github.com/wuapnjie/StickerView

You can add many views as stickers on Sticker View and then you can call method

```
 stickview.createbitmap();
```

This will create bitmap for you and then you can send that bitmap 
It's hardwork , but i am sure  this method will work for you

OR you can try this to create bitmap from view

```
   public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
view.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(),
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
view.draw(canvas);
return bitmap;
  }
```

Comment: this is the single picture only but the thing is points, level and streak is dynamic

Comment: you can acheive functionality , you can add textview as sticker and then you can also update or replace sticker , the sticker can be image, drawable or textview

Comment: this is the easiest way i told you to merge views in single image , other way is using OpenCv library which can be difficult

Comment: i worked on image editing app, and i watermarked text, similily images on image view by using this way

Comment: so I have to define all the views inside stickview?

Comment: yes , you can use sticker view as any other view container , its up to you how to control views position inside sticker view, read library documentation

Comment: try this first and let me know result ,     public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    view.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177187/discussion-between-muhammad-hassaan-and-divyank-vijayvergiya).